# rendering jade file including angular attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to render my index.html in server side using jade
I'm developing my app using angular js.
the problem is here that when I want to render my jade file , I have the error below

> E:\Project\agency_theme6\server\core\coreHttpHandlers\visitor.jade:2
>   head(ng-controller="headCtrl"  prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#')
>   ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

my jade code is here

```
html(lang="en")
    head(ng-controller="headCtrl"  prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#')
        base(href="#!/")
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Language", content="fa")
        meta(name="fragment", content="!")
        meta(name="viewport" , content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Type" , content="text/html; charset=utf-8")
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Style-Type", content="text/css")
        meta(http-equiv="Pragma", content="public")
        meta(http-equiv="Expires", content="-1")
        meta(http-equiv="refresh", content="1800")
        meta(name="generator", content="News Studio, http://www.partdp.ir")
        meta(name="copyright" content="Copyright (c) boursekhan")
        meta(property="og:title", content="")
        meta(property="og:type", content="website")
        meta(property="og:image", content="")
        meta(property="og:url", content="http://boursekhan.ir/")
        meta(property="og:site_name", content="وب سایت تحلیلی خبری اقتصادی بورس خوان")
        meta(property="og:locale", content="fa-IR")
        meta(property="og:description" , content="")
        meta(name="robots", content="ALL,INDEX,FOLLOW")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
        meta(name="rating", content="General")
        meta(name="Revisit", content="30 days")
        meta(name="author", content="bourse khan")
        meta(http-equiv="content-encoding", content="gzip")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")

        link(rel="shortcut icon" href="/public/visitor/img/favicon.ico")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="../../../public/visitor/assets/css/style.css")

        script(type='text/javascript' src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js")
        script(type='text/javascript' src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js")
        script(type='text/javascript' src="../../../public/visitor/assets/js/jquery.js")

body(ng-controller="MainViewCtrl as vm")
    script.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.aside_btn').on('click', function (event) {
                $("body").toggleClass('sidebar_open');
                $('.container').one('click', function (event) {
                    toggle_count = false;
                });
            });
        });
- var loadingTitle = "در حال بارگزاری ...";
    div(class="overlay" ng-show="vm.loading")
        div.loading
            div.loading-box
            div.loading-box
            div.loading-box
            span=loadingTitle

-var homeTitle = "خانه"
    header.main_header
        div.wrapper
            div.row
                div.column_large_8 hidden_small
                    nav
                        ul
                            li
                                a(href="#!/")=homeTitle
                div.column_large_4.column_small_12
                    div.search_box
                        input(type="text" class="input" placeholder="جستجو")
    button.aside_btn
        svg.icon

    main.container
        aside.main_aside
            div.about_me
                header.aside_header
                    h3.
                        {{vm.rule.TYPE}}
                div.my_profile
                    img(src="../../../public/visitor/assets/img/2.jpg")
                    h4.
                        {{vm.rule.TITLE}}
                    span
                p#about-us
            div.favorite_article
                header.aside_header
                    h3.
                        مطالب برگزیده
                ul
                    li(ng-repeat=" listNews in vm.selectedNews ")
                        a(href="#!singlePageNews/{{listNews.POST_ID}}/{{listNews.POST_TITR}}").
                            {{listNews.POST_TITR}}
            div.link_introduction
                header.aside_header
                    h3.
                        معرفی لینک
                ul(ng-repeat="links in vm.linkList" ng-if="links.link != 0")
                    h5.
                        *{{links.cat}}
                    li(style="margin-right: 30px" ng-repeat="link in links.link")
                        a(target="_blank" href="{{link.link}}").
                            {{link.name}}
            div.social_networks
                header.aside_header
                    h3.
                        شبکه های اجتماعی
                div
                    a(href="")
                        svg.icon.color_pintrest
                            use

                    a(href="")
                        svg.icon.color_facebook
                            use

                    a(href="")
                        svg.icon.color_instagram
                            use
                    a(href="")
                        svg.icon.color_skype
                            use
                    a(href="")
                        svg.icon.color_twitter
                            use
                    a(href="")
                        svg.icon.color_gplus
                            use
        div(ng-view)
    script(type="text/javascript" src="../../../public/visitor/lib/require.js"
    data-main="../../../public/visitor/app/main.js")
```